Autodesk Forge Markup - Simple line, possible utilising existing Polygon, Arrow or Rectangle
We're currently looking to implement a simple straight line feature within document markup.
A straight line can be drawn currently by utilising the polygon tool and double clicking at the first point, however, we want to remove the ability of further clicks beyond the first.
I've looked to add a click event listener but it seems a bit of a messy approach.
I've looked at utilising the arrow tool, basically an arrow without the arrow head would do the trick, but I can't seem to find a way of removing the arrow head. It looks to be calculated by the stroke width which I can't unset that, as it's used for the line.
I have found these styles, within markup.editor.styles.arrow, which I've tried to unset.
However, they look to be inherited and return to their original values.

Another option could be a rectangle of fixed height, but I guess for a line it'd be difficult to drag this diagonally.
Is there any known way, I can remove the arrow head from the Arrow tool, or force end the polygon tool after a single click?
Any help appreciated.
Many thanks.
Chrissy

You can create your own tool using THREE JS
You can leverage the snippet below that takes advantage of a Viewer Extension and Viewer's ToolInterface
const LinesToolName = 'lines-tool';
const LinesOverlayName = 'lines-overlay';

class LinesTool extends Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface {
  constructor(viewer, options) {
    super();
    this.viewer = viewer;
    this.names = [LinesToolName];
    this.active = false;
    this.points = []; // Points of the current line
    this.linesMeshes = []; // Mesh representing the currently drawn area
    this.faceNormal = null;
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000, specular: 0xffffff });
    this.lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      linewidth: 3,
      color: 0x000,
      transparent: true,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      depthTest: true,
      depthWrite: false,
      blending: THREE.NoBlending
    });
    this.lineThickness = 0.05;
    // Hack: delete functions defined on the *instance* of a ToolInterface (we want the tool controller to call our class methods instead)
    delete this.register;
    delete this.deregister;
    delete this.activate;
    delete this.deactivate;
    delete this.getPriority;
    delete this.handleMouseMove;
    delete this.handleSingleClick;
    delete this.handleKeyUp;
  }

  register() {
    console.log('LinesTool registered.');
  }

  deregister() {
    console.log('LinesTool unregistered.');
  }

  activate(name, viewer) {
    if (!this.active) {
      this.viewer.overlays.addScene(LinesOverlayName);
      console.log('LinesTool activated.');
      this.active = true;
    }
  }

  deactivate(name) {
    if (this.active) {
      this.viewer.overlays.removeScene(LinesOverlayName);
      console.log('LinesTool deactivated.');
      this.active = false;
      this._reset();
    }
  }

  getPriority() {
    return 13; // Feel free to use any number higher than 0 (which is the priority of all the default viewer tools)
  }

  handleMouseMove(event) {
    if (!this.active) {
      return false;
    }

    this.viewer.clearSelection();
    const currentPoint = this.viewer.clientToWorld(event.canvasX, event.canvasY, true);
    if (!!currentPoint && this.points.length == 1) {
      this._update(currentPoint.point);
    }
    return false;
  }

  handleSingleClick(event, button) {
    if (!this.active) {
      return false;
    }

    if (button === 0) {
      let newPoint = this.viewer.clientToWorld(event.canvasX, event.canvasY, true)
      this.points.push(newPoint);
      if (this.points.length == 2) {
        this._update();
        this._reset();
        return true; // Stop the event from going to other tools in the stack
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  handleKeyUp(event, keyCode) {
    if (this.active) {
      if (keyCode === 27) {
        // Finalize the extrude mesh and initialie a new one
        this.points = [];
        this.mesh = null;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  _update(currentPoint = null) {
    try{
      let firstPoint = this.points[0].point;
      let lastPoint = currentPoint? currentPoint : this.points[1].point;
      this._updateLine(firstPoint, lastPoint);
    }
    catch(ex){
      console.log(ex)
    }
  }

  _updateLine(firstPoint, lastPoint) {
    this._removeLine();
    this._drawLine(firstPoint, lastPoint);
  }

  _removeLine() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.linesMeshes.length; i++) {
      this.viewer.overlays.removeMesh(this.linesMeshes[i], LinesOverlayName);
      this.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true);
    }
  }

  _drawLine(firstPoint, lastPoint) {
    let auxDir1 = lastPoint.clone().sub(firstPoint);
    let auxDown = (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1)).cross(auxDir1).normalize();
    let auxUp = (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1)).cross(auxDir1).normalize();

    let firstPoints = [];
    let firstLineP1 = firstPoint.clone().add(auxUp.clone().multiplyScalar((this.lineThickness) * 0.5));
    firstPoints.push(firstLineP1);
    let firstLineP2 = firstLineP1.clone().add(auxDir1.clone().normalize().multiplyScalar(auxDir1.length()));
    firstPoints.push(firstLineP2);
    let firstLineP3 = firstLineP2.clone().add(auxDown.clone().multiplyScalar(this.lineThickness));
    firstPoints.push(firstLineP3);
    firstPoints.push(firstLineP3);
    firstPoints.push(firstLineP1.clone().add(auxDown.clone().multiplyScalar(this.lineThickness)));
    firstPoints.push(firstLineP1);

    let firstGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    let firstBufferPoints = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < firstPoints.length; i++) {
      firstBufferPoints.push(firstPoints[i].x, firstPoints[i].y, firstPoints[i].z);
    }

    firstGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(firstBufferPoints), 3));

    let line = new THREE.Mesh(firstGeometry, this.lineMaterial);

    this.linesMeshes.push(line);

    if (!this.viewer.overlays.hasScene(LinesOverlayName)) {
      this.viewer.overlays.addScene(LinesOverlayName);
    }
    this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(line, LinesOverlayName);
  }

  _reset() {
    this.points = [];
    this.linesMeshes = [];
  }
}

class LinesToolExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  constructor(viewer, options) {
    super(viewer, options);
    this.tool = new LinesTool(viewer);
    this.button = null;
  }

  async load() {
    this.viewer.toolController.registerTool(this.tool);
    console.log('LinesToolExtension has been loaded.');
    return true;
  }

  async unload() {
    this.viewer.toolController.deregisterTool(this.tool);
    console.log('LinesToolExtension has been unloaded.');
    return true;
  }

  onToolbarCreated(toolbar) {
    const controller = this.viewer.toolController;
    this.button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('lines-tool-button');
    this.button.onClick = (ev) => {
      if (controller.isToolActivated(LinesToolName)) {
        controller.deactivateTool(LinesToolName);
        this.button.setState(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button.State.INACTIVE);
      } else {
        controller.activateTool(LinesToolName);
        this.button.setState(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button.State.ACTIVE);
      }
    };
    this.button.setToolTip('Lines Tool');
    this.group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('lines-tool-group');
    this.group.addControl(this.button);
    const icon = this.button.container.querySelector('.adsk-button-icon');
    let buttonIconUrl = 'https://img.icons8.com/ios/30/line--v1.png';
    if (icon) {
      icon.style.backgroundImage = `url(${buttonIconUrl})`;
      icon.style.backgroundSize = `24px`;
      icon.style.backgroundRepeat = `no-repeat`;
      icon.style.backgroundPosition = `center`;
    }
    toolbar.addControl(this.group);
  }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('LinesToolExtension', LinesToolExtension);

It is implemented at https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-pdf-svg-merger/blob/main/wwwroot/lineExtension.js
Check a gif with this in action at https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-pdf-svg-merger/blob/main/images/linetool.gif

Thanks Joao for the excellent response!!
Last week, I'd taken a look in the src's directory in DevTools and noticed I could see  the other tool modes. I started using the Polyline mode as a base for creating  a new simpler line mode. I seemed to have everything working but then couldn't edit the lines. I think I was missing a call to add Meta data somewhere.
I'll try and implement something similar to the above. It looks a lot more succinct.
Thank you!!
